# Restrict WHEN Jenkins job can run

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

Is there a way to restrict WHEN a job can run in Jenkins? We have nightly work done on some of our slaves for a couple hours where we want to prevent users from executing jobs. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Just mark your slaves temporarily offline. Any jobs requiring those slaves will sit in the build queue until they are ready again.

Comment: Thanks. What if we don't want the job to automatically start once the slave comes back online? In some cases we would want the job to not even be queued but to either not be available for execution or perhaps fail.

Comment: Note: I realize that may or may not be a reasonable request, it was a question from a user and wanted to post it here to see anyone's thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slave+Prerequisites+Plugin